# IncludeAll in databaseChangeLog does not work when ran through maven

Tags: maven, liquibase, maven-compiler-plugin

I have this master changelog:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: db/changelog/changes/
```

When the tests run through intellij everything run smoothly, but when I tried to run through maven, it fails with this error:

```
    at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:83)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:217)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:366)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'db/changelog/changes/'
```

When I include the changelog files one by one, for example

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/changes/001-20200503_1300-Initial.yml
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/changes/liquibase-diff-changeLog.yml
```

everything runs smoothly both intellij and maven. Here are my plugins:

```
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
                        <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                            <version>${spring.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                            <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

and the liquibase.properties

```
url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/doctor-service
username= verality
password= verality
driver= org.postgresql.Driver
changeLogFile=db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/liquibase-diff-changeLog.yml
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/liquibase-new-changeLog.yml
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:io.happyharbor.verality?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

I tried removing the surefire plugin, but there was not difference, so it seems that the mavel-compile-plugin should take the blame. Please note that this issues only manifestates when I run a test through maven. If I deploy, everything runs smoothly again.
It seems that this was a known back on earlier versions, but it should have been fixed now. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem and I didn't find a better solution (removing  *includeAll* tag wasn't an acceptable option in my case) except increasing the version of Liquibase itself from 3.8.6 to **4.2.2** and it has fixed this issue. It's generally a good idea to have the newest possible versions of libraries.